# Need suggestion on process/architecture for multiple releases simultaneously for a single product

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, tfs

I'm working with a product development firm having multiple releases simultaneously for same product.
We have around 4 environments with their own copy of SQL database and TFS branches.

Now the problem is we spend lot of time on merging code, resolving conflicts and merging within various branches to make sure we do not mess with deployment.
We are taking help of Redgate tool(new for this) for sql db side management but still feel like we are not in good condition.

Can you please suggest me best architecture/solution or set of tools that can be implemented ?

Comment: We are multiple team of 4-5 members working on different releases makes us to spend hours in manual merge and deployment

Comment: Why do you work on multiple releases simultaneously? Is one release not built on another?

Comment: Yes, we have small releases simultaneously going on with same code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the number of merging related activities that are going on then we need to reduce the number of merging activities. This is not going to be an easy thing to change as the culture and expectation within your organisation is currently tuned to produce this result.

You need to move towards a single line, or single branching model. If you are using Git then you can still use many short lived activity branches for Hotfixes or Releases as laid down in GitFlow, but your source line where you add all new code (DEV, MASTER, TRUNK, Main, whatever) should be a single line. As soon as you have feature or version branches you are in the world of merging.

There are a number of engineering activities and practices that you can use to support much of what you are physically doing now in the new model:

1. **Feature toggles** - This is your primary engineering solution for merging. If you are working on a single code line, and always have coders check in working code, then feature toggles allow you to ship features that are half done and you don't want folks to see. You hide them.... Now the first thing that you are going to throw out is "but we do database work and you can't do that there", and you would be wrong. Many organisations practice feature toggles and include database work. You need to have a solid and consistent practice of 'additive only' so that you don't break existing work and actually do work to make sure that both a new feature and an old one can coexist. There is work in that, but not as much as merging (in my experience) and not as error or bug prone. One key to remember is to think of them as **Feature** toggle and not code toggles. If you add a new feature then hide it till its ready. If you are incrementally improving an existing feature then just ship the new functionality. Achieving this WILL be hard and will require courage to implement major cultural changes at your organisation from coders and testers, all the way up to sales and management.
2. **Definition of Done** - Which leads to the question of how do we maintain quality in this new world of feature toggles? Think about this: if you have 3 feature teams all working on different functionality and one team decided to reduce their quality but what they have is buggy but good enough, what would be the impact? You are protected from this in a branching model until then end when you make all sorts of compromises to make everyone's mediocre (or just plane crap) code work together. Now we have to have this on every check-in and every release. So what do you need? You need a shared and agreed Definition of Done that represents the quality bar that must be met to ship. Without it you will have chaos. The cultural issue here is that you need everyone, every coder, and every tester, on board with the sacrosanct nature of the DOD. No you cant just compromise just this once as it will have a knock on effect.
3. **Reduce cycle time** - Which leads to our ship cycle. You need to 'ship' more regularly. Or more specifically you need to create potentially shippable increments of working software on a regular basis. This support the above in a number of ways, but first and foremost it reduces the amount of work that is under way. This will help reduce the complexity and help teams focus. With what is in effect shorter batch sizes we can get a much more regular adherence to the definition of done and have those touch points of "working software with no further work required to ship it". The side advantages here is that you increase your business ability to change as they can change at the end of each cycle sure in the knowledge that unfinished features are not going to in fact introduce complexity. You also gain the ability to inspect and adapt more frequently. Most companies, on gathering the evidence, find that more than 60% of their software is used little if ever. Lets use the reduced cycle time to get users in front of the software and only focus on building the 40% that they care about. (whoa! did we just get a 60% efficiency gain there?)

There are a number of other supporting practices that it would make a lot of sense for you to adopt to get there and I would probably recommend that you read the Scrum Guide (http://www.scrumguides.org/) and think about how you might start moving towards the goals above.